# How can you get the message ID of currently sent message sent from telegram bot?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I have created a message and sent it using `sendMessage` with Telegram API.

***How can I get the message ID of currently sent message?***

```java
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;

...

SendMessage message = new SendMessage(); 
message.setChatId(chat_id)

try {
    execute(message);
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// here is where I would like to get the id of the message I just sent above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api#send-message):

> Send message
>
> All send requests (`SendMessage`, `SendPhoto`, `SendLocation`...) return `SendResponse` object that contains Message.

So you'll need to capture the response of `execute(message)` to get the `SendResponse`.

The message ID will be available on that object.

---

Example code:

```java
public class App  {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        long chatId = 1234567;

        TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot("ABCDEF......");

        SendResponse response = bot.execute(new SendMessage(chatId, "Hello!"));
        Message message = response.message();
        long messageId = message.messageId();

        System.out.println("Message id :");
        System.out.println(messageId);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Shows the following output:

```
Message id :
449
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a message and sent it using sendMessage with Telegram API.
How can I get the message ID of currently sent message?

i do:

```
SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
message.setChatId(example);
message.setText(text);

// and here i want to get message id of this message
```

I have already found the answer (using SendResponse), but it is outdated

ps: or mb im dumbasses

Comment: Actually i finish it its was

SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
message.setChatId(example);
message.setText(text);

try {
            messageId = execute(message).getMessageId(); <-- just add in end of execute get
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }